# Raspberry Pi 3B and RFID RC522 - Python TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, typeerror, rfid

I've been messing around with Raspberry Pi and RFID and found this tutorial:

https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/

Everything went fine with the installation but when I'm running the script it presents an error.

This is the problem:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/MFRC522-python $ sudo python Write.py
/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py:115: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Write.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522.MFRC522()
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.MFRC522_Init()
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 390, in MFRC522_Init
    self.MFRC522_Reset();
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 120, in MFRC522_Reset
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_RESETPHASE)
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 123, in Write_MFRC522
    spi.transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E,val))
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This is the Write.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = raw_input('New data:')
        print("Now place your tag to write")
        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I can't find the solution to this problem in any place. Already tried to use Python 3 and other libraries but I'm still getting the error.

UPDATE :

Edited this on MFRC522.py file :

```
def Write_MFRC522(self, addr, val):
    spi.transfer( (addr<<1)&0x7E, val )
```

And now I get this output :

```
/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py:115: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
First argument must be a valid dictionary.: Success
Aborted
```

Comment: Please post the content of Write.py

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: Do simple GPIO set operations work (without simplemfrc522)  ? Did you enable GPIO and SPI? If not, go to sudo raspi-config and enable it.

Comment: Please include the error message as text, not as a picture.

Comment: Already did and they work well. Yes I enabled GPIO and SPI on Raspberry Config and checked if they were enabled.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Updated.Thank you.

Comment: @mkrieger1 couldn't comment your answer, I've updated my question.

Comment: The new error message tells you that you should pass a dictionary instead of a number (you are passing `25`). Did you read the documentation of `GPIO.setup`? It should tell you what this dictionary should be.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Made a few changes : `def __init__(self, dev='/dev/spidev0.0', spd=1000000):
    spi.openSPI(device=dev,speed=spd)
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.output(22, 1)
    self.MFRC522_Init()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue for at least 2 hours... now i found out, that the IRQ channel of RC522 has to be soldered to pin 18 of raspberry PI... I also renewed the soldered pins on the rc522, now it works fine.. seems to be a mechanic issue, no software problem..

This also helps: https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522

Befor (error msg):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/MFRC522-python $ sudo python Write.py
/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py:115: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Write.py", line 6, in <module>
    reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/SimpleMFRC522.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.READER = MFRC522.MFRC522()
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.MFRC522_Init()
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 390, in MFRC522_Init
    self.MFRC522_Reset();
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 120, in MFRC522_Reset
    self.Write_MFRC522(self.CommandReg, self.PCD_RESETPHASE)
  File "/home/pi/MFRC522-python/MFRC522.py", line 123, in Write_MFRC522
    spi.transfer(((addr<<1)&0x7E,val))
TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Now:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python rfidreader2.py 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pi_rc522-2.2.1-py2.7.egg/pirc522/rfid.py:78: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
clean up
Tag detected
UID: [169, 112, 111, 72, 254]
Reading block 10: (False, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! Please only post an answer when you want to answer the question. In else cases, consider commenting or voting !

Comment: Worked! Thanks! Want to share your Read.py ?

Comment: Hi, i am actually working on it - open to share when it can be used as personalized control utility for smart home purpose ;-)

Comment: Worked for me too! I've been trying for days to get my MFRC522 up and working.

Answer (score 13):

The problem comes from the https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py library.
If you roll back to 8cce26b9ee6e69eb041e9d5665944b88688fca68 it should work

Make sure to run the setup again after rollback.

```
git clone https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git
git checkout 8cce26b9ee6e69eb041e9d5665944b88688fca68
sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py/issues/23
I'm getting the same issue after I updated SPI...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . My solution was:

```
git clone https://github.com/lthiery/SPI-Py.git
cd SPI Py
sudo python setup.py install
```

it works after these commands

```
 sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed IRQ cable and it worked for me. Although I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

To be sure test your scripts using root.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30233609)